# [Typescript]: How to decompress .tar.gz file and get files in memory

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, extract, tar.gz

I'm developing an Angular project without BE service.

I'd like to know how to decompress .tar.gz file and process it **in memory(not it in the disk)**.

> ex: read and parse specific files.

I followed this solution to decompress it:

> [How do I extract data from a .tar.gz file (stored in the cloud) from a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65446607/how-do-i-extract-data-from-a-tar-gz-file-stored-in-the-cloud-from-a-browser))

- Here is my code

```
import * as pako from "pako";
import * as untar from "untar";
...

onFileSelected(e: Event) {
    const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (target.files) {
      
      //decompress file
      const f = target.files[0];
      
      f.arrayBuffer()
       .then(pako.inflate)
       .then((arr) => arr.buffer)
       .then(untar)   //<--  Error: untar pkg has no @types/untar                
       .then(files => {                
         console.log(files);
        });
    }
  }
```

The solution guides me to use `Pako` and `untar` packages to decompress the loaded file stream.

But `untar` pkg doesn't have `@types/untar` to provide the pkg module for Typescript.

The post's reply also suggests using `tarball` pkg, but it still has no `@types/tarball`

So I can not continue decompressing work.

**Does anyone have any ideas to decompress .tar.gz?**

many thanks :)

Comment: If they don't have types, just tell typescript to not try to enforce typing for them? Just add typing to _your_ code if a dependency doesn't have types, if that dependency is the best way to do something in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use `any` Type**: If the package doesn't have TypeScript types, you can use `any` to bypass type checking. For example, `const untar: any = require('untar');`.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, thanks for your reminder.
In Angular project, I can set tsconfig.app.json to ignore this pkg's type definition.